# Access property of element not directly in form in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, validation

Is it possible to access $dirty property of some element which is not put directly in form, something like:

```
<form name="form">
    <div name="divInForm">
        <input type="text" name="inputInDivInForm">
    </div>
    <button ng-disabled="form.divInForm.inputInDivInForm.$dirty"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Using `"form.inputInDivInForm.$dirty"` will do it.

Comment: inputInDivInForm is inside ng-repeat maybe that's a problem

Answer (score 1):

At first, you **must** set `ngModel` to your `input`, otherwise it won't work.

Also, you have to access it this way: `form.inputInDivInForm.$dirty`.

Look at this simple *example*:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="form">
    <div name="divInForm">
      <input type="text" ng-model="any" name="inputInDivInForm">
    </div>        
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.inputInDivInForm.$dirty">Click</button>
  </form>
  <pre ng-bind="form.inputInDivInForm | json"></pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have ng-model showing data from a controller, but still does not work